# Execute if condition where all elements are in variables in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, logical-operators

Sorry for my bad English, I'm translating Unix shell code to PowerShell and I get Unix code where a if statement use just variables like this:
`if( $val1 $op $val2)...`
Can anyone tell me if there is in Powershell a similar way to do that?
I'd like not use switch to validate each operator.

thanks ¡

Comment: If($val1 -and $op -and $val2){...}

Answer (score 0):

The exact reference you're looking for is the command:
`Get-Help about_Logical_Operators`
There's dozens of detailed articles explaining the details on how PowerShell handles certain concepts. You can get the whole list with `Get-Help about`

From the about_Logical_Operators article:

```
    Operator  Description                      Example
    --------  ------------------------------   ------------------------
    -and      Logical and. TRUE only when      (1 -eq 1) -and (1 -eq 2)
              both statements are TRUE.         False
```

A PowerShell equivalent to your sample code might look like:

```
$val1 = $True
$op = 1
$val2 = "Not Empty"
if ($val1 -and $op -and $val2)
   {
   Write-Host "All three conditions are true!"
   }
```

Comment: Oh maybe I did not explain so well, My question is that I have a variable who have the operator, for example:  $MyOp = "-le" and I have 2 vars like this: $var1= 5, $var2=6, so i have to make a if like "Dynamic" on this way:
if( $var1  $MyOp  $var2) {} ..

Comment: Oh! I completely understand now! You want to make the boolean operator itself a variable. It's obvious now when I look back at the variable name.

Comment: My guess is that you can do this with Invoke-Expression, but I can't test right now. Just be careful with that commandlet. If a malicious user is able to get their own code into a variable, it might get executed.